# Query to get a all tags field values and pour all value in field

Tags: php, sql, drupal

**UPDATE :**
i need get a all values of tags field !

**MY Query :**

```
$query = db_select('node', 'node');
$query->fields('tagsdata',array('name'));
$query->fields('node', array('nid'));

$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_tags', 'tags', 'tags.entity_id = node.nid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_index', 'tagsindex', 'tagsindex.nid = tags.entity_id');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data','tagsdata','tagsdata.tid = tags.field_tags_tid AND node.nid = tagsindex.nid');

$result = $query->execute();

    while( $record = $result->fetchAssoc() ) { 
        $items[] = $record;
    }
```

**AND MY CODE :**

```
    //SORT
   array_multisort(array_column($items, 'nid'), $items);
foreach ($items as $row) {

    $hash[$row[nid]] = $row;
}

$resultfinal = ($hash);
    // END SORT 
foreach($resultfinal as $finalarrays)
      {
         $tags=$finalarrays['name'];
         print_R ($tags);
      }
```

**WITH above code just return one and first value of tags, i need to print all of them !**

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT mysql function to get all value imploded by comma :

```
$result = db_query("SELECT tags.entity_id as nid, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tdata  FROM field_data_field_tags 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data t ON t.tid = tags.field_tags_tid 
WHERE tags.entity_type = :type GROUP BY tags.entity_id", 
array(':type' => 'node'))->fetchAllKeyed();
```

NB : sometimes you have too much string to concat so you need to increase limit before by :

```
db_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10000');
$result = db_query("SELECT tags.entity_id as nid, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tdata  FROM field_data_field_tags 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data t ON t.tid = tags.field_tags_tid 
WHERE tags.entity_type = :type GROUP BY tags.entity_id", 
array(':type' => 'node'))->fetchAllKeyed();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
foreach($result as $nid => $tags) {
  echo $nid . ' : '.$tags;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but not work , in this case i should pour all tags value in the `tdata` field with `foreach` or somthing else, can you make another suggestion?

Comment: You didn't try my code , it make exactly you want , i can't do more to bring help to you

Comment: i try that but no result ! just return all arrays without all tags field value!